# request.user returns None Django social-auth-app-django

Tags: python, django, azure, django-socialauth

I am a newbie in django social auth. I am using `social-auth-app-django` to authenticate Microsoft Azure AD user. Authentication process works well and user object is created inside the database. But request.user is returing null inside view.

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
    # 'social.apps.django_app.default',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',

            ],
        },
    },
]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social.backends.azuread.AzureADOAuth2',
 )
#settings.py
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = {
  'pipeline.new_users_handler'
}
```

View

```
def home(request):
   """Renders the home page."""
   assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)

   context = {
       'title':'Home Page',
       'year':datetime.now().year,
       'request': request,
       'user': request.user,
     }
   context_instance = RequestContext(request,context)
   return render(
     request,
     'index.html',context)
```

The request.user works fine when I login as admin or any other user created using admin. The issue is when authenticated via social auth.

Comment: did you find solution if yes please guide me

Answer (score 1):

you dont need all of this, use the simple syntax

```
def home(request):
   context = {
       'title':'Home Page',
       'year':datetime.now().year,
       'request': request,
       'user': request.user,
     }
   return render(
     request,
     'index.html',context)
```

but `request.user` will return null until the user is not logged in

add this to your MIDDLEWARE at the end

```
'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
```

add this to templates context processor at the end

```
'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # <--
'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # <--
```

Comment: Even after authenticating with Azure, request.user is still None

Comment: I already have the two conext processors added. Adding middleware `'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware', ` didnt fix the issue

Comment: @SudheerK, were you able to solve this by any chance?

Comment: @ShashankHegde Since it is more than 6 years I dont remember it correctly. I was able to fix it. If I remember it correctly, the user_id was set in the session after registration. I used the request.session.get('user_id'). I am not 100 percentage sure. Sorry about that

Comment: Np, thanks. My issue was the Auth provider was using Tenants and I had configured my server with AzureADOAuth2 instead of AzureADTenantOAuth2.